# Is there an alternate way to input the index without using a variable?

Tags: python

I have to store shipment in a list,like the name and quantity,and when I create a sale,the program will ask for the product name,match it from the list,find the index number and use the index number to find its quantity.But I do not know how to transfer the index number to `quantity()` without using a variable.

Other than variable,I also tried to use `TM.index(a)`.But so far i can only find out that `Quantity()` only allows numbers.

```
TM=[fish,crabs ]  

 Quantity=[100,20  ]

 TM2=input("product name :")

 if TM2.lower() in TM:

      a=TM2.lower()

      b = TM.index(a)

      c = Quantity(b)
```

I expected the output to be this:

```
TM2= Crabs

a= crabs

b= 1

c=Quantity(1)

c=20
```

but instead I got: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: `Quantity[b]` ?

Comment: b is the variable that contains the index.If I have 100 fish and 20 crabs so if I put them in two different list:TM=[ fish,crabs] and Quantity=[ 100,20].In theory,if I find the index of TM,I could use the index number which is stored in variable b to find the quantity.Example:TM(0)=fish so Quantity(0)=100.

Comment: Yes, but "Quantity" is not a method, is a list. You should index it as Quantity[b] and NOT Quantity(b)

Comment: The error is not because you are using a variable to access list element, but with using paranthesis instead of square brackets. See dupe.

Comment: I was at the assumption that using ( ) is the correct way,probably because previously I used .append() and . count().In addition,I believed that using [ ] will completely change the list,example:Quantity[b],will caused the list Quantity [ 100,20] to become Quantity [ b ]

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble because you're using the wrong data structure. You want a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). It works like this:

```
product_to_quantity = {
    'fish': 100,
    'crabs': 20
}

which = input('product name? ').lower()

quantity = product_to_quantity[which]

print(quantity)
```

If you run this and input `fish`, it will print `100`.

Note the square brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()`. Square brackets are used to get items out of both dictionaries and lists. In your original code, you would have used `Quantity[b]` to get the `b`th element of the list.